# How to highlight area with background color between selected date range in vega chart using marks type rect

Tags: linechart, vega

In line chart, x-axis I have time stamp and y-axis with numerical value, I'm able to draw a line (y axis) with numeric value between specific period of time stamp(starttime and endtime).Instead of line required to highlight area . Tried using marks type rect but with hardcode values width[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQpFn.png) and height, required to make it dynamic by the coordinates or some other way .

Spec:

```json
 {
   "$schema":"https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
   "autosize":{
      "type":"pad",
      "resize":true
   },
   "padding":5,
   "width":800,
   "height":200,
   "style":"",
   "signals":[
      {
         "name":"x3",
         "value":1607592500000
      },
      {
         "name":"x2",
         "value":1607592500000
      },
      {
         "name":"x",
         "value":1607592500000
      },
      {
         "name":"Endtimex3",
         "value":1607998500000
      },
      {
         "name":"Endtimex2",
         "value":0
      },
      {
         "name":"Endtimex",
         "value":0
      },
        
       {"name": "nominaly", "value": 4}, 
      {
         "name":"y",
         "value":0
      },
      {
         "name":"y2",
         "value":200
      },
      {
         "name":"strokeWidth",
         "value":2
      },
      {
         "name":"strokeCap",
         "value":"butt"
      },
      {
         "name":"strokeDash",
         "value":[
            8,
            4
         ]
      },
      {
         "name":"y3",
         "value":60
      },
      {
         "name":"dx",
         "value":-15
      },
      {
         "name":"dy",
         "value":15
      }, 
      {
         "name":"angle",
         "value":0
      },
      {
         "name":"limit",
         "value":0
      },
      {
         "name":"align",
         "value":"right"
      },
      {
         "name":"alignleft",
         "value":"left"
      },
      {
         "name":"baseline",
         "value":"alphabetic"
      },
      {
         "name":"bottom",
         "value":"bottom"
      }, 
      {
      "name": "interpolate", "value": "linear" 
      },
      { "name": "color", "value": "both"},
      {
         "name":"anchor",
         "value":[
            0,
            0
         ],
         "on":[
            {
               "events":"wheel",
               "update":"[invert('x', x()), invert('y', y())]"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "name":"zoom",
         "value":1,
         "on":[
            {
               "events":"wheel!",
               "force":true,
               "update":"pow(1.001, event.deltaY * pow(16, event.deltaMode))"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "name":"xdom",
         "update":"xext",
         "on":[
            {
               "events":{
                  "signal":"zoom"
               },
               "update":"[time(anchor[0]) + (time(xdom[0]) - time(anchor[0])) * zoom, time(anchor[0]) + (time(xdom[1]) - time(anchor[0])) * zoom]"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "data":[
      {
         "name":"table",
         "values": [ {"count":1,"category":"volume","dateTime":1608006600000,"anomalous":true},{"count":2,"category":"volume","dateTime":1608000900000,"anomalous":true},{"count":3,"category":"volume","dateTime":1608011400000,"anomalous":true},{"count":4,"category":"volume","dateTime":1608005700000,"anomalous":true},{"count":7,"category":"volume","dateTime":1608003300000,"anomalous":true},{"count":4,"category":"volume","dateTime":1608000000000,"anomalous":true},{"count":2,"category":"volume","dateTime":1608009000000,"anomalous":true},{"count":6,"category":"volume","dateTime":1608012300000,"anomalous":true},{"count":2,"category":"volume","dateTime":1606959600000,"anomalous":false},{"count":0,"category":"volume","dateTime":1607263800000,"anomalous":false},{"count":0,"category":"volume","dateTime":1607102700000,"anomalous":false},{"count":5,"category":"volume","dateTime":1606971000000,"anomalous":false},{"count":4,"category":"volume","dateTime":1606951200000,"anomalous":false},{"count":6,"category":"volume","dateTime":1607735700000,"anomalous":false},{"count":4,"category":"volume","dateTime":1607971200000,"anomalous":false},{"count":4,"category":"volume","dateTime":1606989000000,"anomalous":false},{"count":5,"category":"volume","dateTime":1607386500000,"anomalous":false},{"count":0,"category":"volume","dateTime":1606834500000,"anomalous":false},{"count":5,"category":"volume","dateTime":1607355300000,"anomalous":false},{"count":4,"category":"volume","dateTime":1606977600000,"anomalous":false},{"count":5,"category":"volume","dateTime":1607243400000,"anomalous":false}]
      },
      {
         "name":"data_0",
         "source":"table",
         "transform":[
            {
               "type":"formula",
               "expr":"toDate(datum[\"dateTime\"])",
               "as":"dateTime"
            },
            {
               "type":"extent",
               "field":"dateTime",
               "signal":"xext"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "marks":[
        {
      "type": "rect",
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "fill": {"value": "#939597"},
          "stroke": {"value": "#652c90"}
        },
        "update": {
          "x": {"signal": "x", "scale":"x"},
          "y": {"signal": "y"},
          "width": {"signal": "280"},
          "height": {"signal": "100"},
          "opacity": {"value": 1}, 
          "strokeWidth": {"signal": "strokeWidth"},
          "fillOpacity": {"signal": "1"},
          "strokeOpacity": {"signal": "0"}
        },
        "hover": {
          "opacity": {"value": 0.5}
        }
      }
    },
      {
         "type":"rule",
         "clip":true,
         "encode":{
            "enter":{
               "stroke":{
                  "value":"red"
               }
            },
            "update":{
               "x":{
                  "signal":"x",
                  "scale":"x"
               },
               "y":{
                  "signal":"y"
               },
               "x2":{
                  "signal":"x2",
                  "scale":"x"
               },
               "y2":{
                  "signal":"y2"
               },
               "strokeWidth":{
                  "signal":"strokeWidth"
               },
               "strokeDash":{
                  "signal":"strokeDash"
               },
               "strokeCap":{
                  "signal":"strokeCap"
               },
               "opacity":{
                  "value":1
               }
            },
            "hover":{
               "opacity":{
                  "value":0.5
               }
            }
         }
      },
      {
         "type":"rule",
         "clip":true,
         "encode":{
            "enter":{
               "stroke":{
                  "value":"red"
               }
            },
            "update":{
               "x":{
                  "signal":"Endtimex3",
                  "scale":"x"
               },
               "y":{
                  "signal":"y"
               },
               "x2":{
                  "signal":"Endtimex3",
                  "scale":"x"
               },
               "y2":{
                  "signal":"y2"
               },
               "strokeWidth":{
                  "signal":"strokeWidth"
               },
               "strokeDash":{
                  "signal":"strokeDash"
               },
               "strokeCap":{
                  "signal":"strokeCap"
               },
               "opacity":{
                  "value":1
               }
            },
            "hover":{
               "opacity":{
                  "value":0.5
               }
            }
         }
      }, 
      {
         "type":"text",
         "clip":true,
         "encode":{
            "enter":{
               "fill":{
                  "value":"black"
               },
               "text":{
                  "value":"Anomaly Start Time"
               }
            },
            "update":{
               "opacity":{
                  "value":1
               },
               "x":{
                  "signal":"x3",
                  "scale":"x"
               },
               "y":{
                  "signal":"y3"
               },
               "dx":{
                  "signal":"dx"
               },
               "angle":{
                  "signal":"angle"
               },
               "align":{
                  "signal":"align"
               },
               "baseline":{
                  "signal":"baseline"
               },
               "limit":{
                  "signal":"limit"
               }
            },
            "hover":{
               "opacity":{
                  "value":0.5
               }
            }
         }
      },
      {
         "type":"text",
         "clip":true,
         "encode":{
            "enter":{
               "fill":{
                  "value":"black"
               },
               "text":{
                  "value":"Anomaly End Time"
               }
            },
            "update":{
               "opacity":{
                  "value":1
               },
               "x":{
                  "signal":"Endtimex3",
                  "scale":"x"
               },
               "y":{
                  "signal":"y3"
               },
               "dx":{
                  "signal":"dy"
               },
               "angle":{
                  "signal":"angle"
               },
               "align":{
                  "signal":"alignleft"
               },
               "baseline":{
                  "signal":"baseline"
               },
               "limit":{
                  "signal":"limit"
               }
            },
            "hover":{
               "opacity":{
                  "value":0.5
               }
            }
         }
      }, 
       {
         "type":"text",
         "clip":true,
         "encode":{
            "enter":{
               "fill":{
                  "value":"black"
               },
               "text":{
                  "value":"Nominal Volume"
               }
            },
            "update":{
               "opacity":{
                  "value":1
               },
               "x":{
                  "signal":"x3",
                  "scale":"x"
               },
               "y":{
                  "signal":"nominaly",
                  "scale": "y"
               }, 
               "dx":{
                  "signal":"dy"
               },
               "angle":{
                  "signal":"angle"
               },
               "align":{
                  "signal":"alignleft"
               },
               "baseline":{
                  "signal":"bottom"
               },
               "limit":{
                  "signal":"limit"
               }
            },
            "hover":{
               "opacity":{
                  "value":0.5
               }
            }
         }
      },
       {
         "type":"rule",
         "clip":true,
         "encode":{
            "enter":{
               "stroke":{
                  "value":"grey"
               }
            },
            "update":{
               
               "x":{
                  "signal":"x3",
                  "scale":"x"
               },
               "y":{
                  "signal":"nominaly",
                  "scale": "y"
               },
               "x2":{
                  "signal":"Endtimex3",
                  "scale":"x"
               },
               "y2":{
                  "signal":"nominaly",
                  "scale": "y"
               },
               "width": {"signal": "100"},
               "height": {"signal": "150"},
               "strokeWidth":{
                  "signal":"strokeWidth"
               },
               "strokeDash":{
                  "signal":"strokeDash"
               },
               "strokeCap":{
                  "signal":"strokeCap"
               },
               "opacity":{
                  "value":1
               }
            },
            "hover":{
               "opacity":{
                  "value":0.5
               }
            }
         }
      },
      {
         "name":"pathgroup",
         "type":"group",
         "clip":true,
         "from":{
            "facet":{
               "name":"faceted_path_main",
               "data":"data_0",
               "groupby":[
                  "category"
               ]
            }
         },
         "encode":{
            "update":{
               "width":{
                  "field":{
                     "group":"width"
                  }
               },
               "height":{
                  "field":{
                     "group":"height"
                  }
               }
            }
         },
         "marks":[
            {
               "name":"marks",
               "type":"line",
               "style":[
                  "line"
               ],
               "sort":{
                  "field":"datum[\"dateTime\"]",
                  "order":"descending"
               },
               "from":{
                  "data":"faceted_path_main"
               },
               "encode":{
                  "update":{
                     "interpolate":{
                        "signal":"interpolate"
                     },
                     "opacity":[
                        {
                           "value":0.7
                        }
                     ],
                     "stroke":[
                        {
                           "scale":"color",
                           "field":"category"
                        }
                     ],
                     "tooltip":{
                        "signal":"{\"Time\": timeFormat(datum[\"dateTime\"], '%b %d, %Y %H:%M'), \"Count\": format(datum[\"count\"], \"\"), \"category\": ''+datum[\"category\"]}"
                     },
                     "x":{
                        "scale":"x",
                        "field":"dateTime"
                     },
                     "y":{
                        "scale":"y",
                        "field":"count"
                     },
                     "defined":{
                        "signal":"datum[\"dateTime\"] !== null && !isNaN(datum[\"dateTime\"]) && datum[\"count\"] !== null && !isNaN(datum[\"count\"])"
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "scales":[
     

      {
         "name":"x",
         "type":"time",
         "domain":{
            "data":"data_0",
            "field":"dateTime"  
         },
         "range":[
            0,
            {
               "signal":"width"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "name":"y",
         "type":"linear",
         "domain":{
            "data":"data_0",
            "field":"count"
         },
         "range":[
            {
               "signal":"height"
            },
            0
         ],
         "nice":true,
         "zero":true
      },
      {
         "name":"color",
         "type":"ordinal",
         "domain":{
            "data":"data_0",
            "field":"category",
            "sort":true
         },
         "range":{
            "scheme":"accent"
         }
      }
   ],
   "axes":[
      {
         "scale":"x",
         "orient":"bottom",
         "grid":false,
         "title":"Time(5 minutes window)",
         "labelFlush":true,
         "labelOverlap":true,
         "labelSeparation":10,
         "tickCount":{
            "signal":"ceil(width/10)"
         },
         "titleColor":"black",
         "labelColor":"black",
         "zindex":1,
         "encode":{
            "labels":{
               "update":{
                  "text":{
                     "signal":"timeFormat(datum.value, '%b %d, %Y %H:%M')"
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      },
      {
         "scale":"y",
         "orient":"left",
         "grid":false,
         "title":"Count",
         "labelOverlap":true,
         "labelSeparation":10,
         "tickCount":{
            "signal":"ceil(height/40)"
         },
         "titleColor":"black",
         "labelColor":"black",
         "zindex":1
      }
   ],
   "legends":[
      {
         "stroke":"color",
         "title":"",
         "titleColor":"black",
         "labelColor":"black",
         "orient":"top-left",
         "encode":{
            "symbols":{
               "name":"legendSymbol",
               "interactive":true,
               "update":{
                  "fill":{
                     "value":"transparent"
                  },
                  "strokeWidth":{
                     "value":2
                  },
                  "opacity":[
                     {
                        "value":0.7
                     }
                  ],
                  "size":{
                     "value":64
                  }
               }
            },
            "labels":{
               "name":"legendLabel",
               "interactive":true,
               "update":{
                  "opacity":[
                     {
                        "value":1
                     }
                  ]
               }
            }
         }
      }
   ],
   "config":{
      "axisY":{
         "minExtent":30
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the fix by using rect mark .

```
            "type":"rect",
            "encode":{
                "enter":{
                  "x":{
                      "scale":"x",
                      "signal":"x3"
                  },
                  "x2":{
                      "scale":"x",
                      "signal":"Endtimex3"
                  },
                  "y":{
                      "value":0
                  },
                  "y2":{
                      "signal":"height"
                  } ,
                  "fill":{
                      "value":"red"
                  },
                  "stroke":{
                      "value":"red"
                  },
                  "strokeWidth":{
                      "value":1
                  },
                  "fillOpacity":{
                      "value":1
                  },
                  "opacity":{
                      "value":0.1
                  } 
                } 
            }
            }
```